# Is positional encoding (in transformers) an estimation of the relative positions of words in the training corpus texts?

Tags: bert, transformer

Is this some kind of estimation of the relative positions of words in the training texts? are they creating some kind of statistical "distribution" of words? is "cat" usually 2 or 3 words away from "milk" in English language? things have to have a meaning, havent they?  Is BERT just adding some aditional dimensions to the vector space to include info on the relative positions of words?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, we should clarify that positional encodings are not necessarily applied to words but **tokens**. Nowadays, using subword tokens is the norm, and infrequent words can be divided into many subword tokens.

Regarding the role of positional encoding: according to research, positional encodings have different roles depending on where they are used:

- Transformer decoders for autoregressive language modeling: positional embeddings learn about absolute positions (see [*What Do Position Embeddings Learn? An Empirical Study of Pre-Trained Language Model Positional Encoding*](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/2020.emnlp-main.555/)).
- Masked language models (i.e. BERT): the positional encodings only help differentiating between tokens, and the order does not actually matter much (see [*Masked Language Modeling and the Distributional Hypothesis: Order Word Matters Pre-training for Little*](https://arxiv.org/abs/2104.06644)).

**So, to answer the question**:

No, positional encodings do not estimate the relative positions of words in the training corpus texts.

Comment: Thanks for these 2 interesting and relevant papers.  In the second one is mentioned that Masked language models (MLMs) succeed on downstream tasks "almost entirely due to their ability to model higher-order word co-occurrence statistics". So it is not they are estimating the relative positions of words but their co-ocurrence in a window, arent they?

Comment: Note that the statement is not referring to positional encodings but to MLMs as a whole.

Comment: What I meant is that I don't think you can derive that positional encodings are estimation co-ocurrence of a window, just that the whole MLM models co-occurrence statistics.

Comment: Also, if you found the answer useful, please consider upvoting it, and also marking it as correct if deemed so.

Comment: Would love to upvote it but I still dont have the reputation needed to do so :) maybe if someone upvote the questions I made then I would be able to update the answers ;)

Comment: You can always accept the answer with the tick symbol below the answer score.

Comment: Done!. I still dont have the reputation needed to upvote it :)... at least I dont have a "bad" reputation :)

Comment: Is interested that you mention that "the whole MLM models co-occurrence statistics". In the end this is what a MLM is doing right?

Comment: That's what it seems from that article.